# I'm facing an error in a project using monaco editor. Error: Cannot find module 'metadata.js'

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, webpack-plugin

This is happening in a react project using webpack. The project is created using create-react-app

After a lot of debugging, I have found the cause of the error to be in the following file.

[monaco-editor-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/webpack-plugin/src/index.ts)

It happens in the function below:

```
function getEditorMetadata(monacoEditorPath: string | undefined): EditorMetadata {
    const metadataPath = resolveMonacoPath('metadata.js', monacoEditorPath);
    return require(metadataPath);
}
```

Line no: 58

But I'm not sure from where that file should come from. I have googled it but seems like there are no traces of this error to be found.

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the issue. Firstly, I commented   `new MonacoEditorWebpackPlugin()` in the webpack config plugins.

```
 plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src/index.html"), // index html file
    }),
    new MonacoEditorWebpackPlugin(), // code-view - monaco-editor
  ],
```

Then, the issue I got was that there was a module missing - `monaco-editor`

Though, I was already using - `@monaco-editor/react`

But I installed, `monaco-editor` and then it worked.

Comment: Rock on man! This worked for me! Here's my next.config.js file: ```/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css")
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin")

const nextConfig = {
 webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
  config.plugins.push(
   new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
    languages: ["javascript", "typescript"],
    filename: "static/[name].worker.js",
   })
  )
  return config
 },
}

module.exports = nextConfig``` ...and installing ```monaco-editor``` also cleared it up!